# postfix not transporting mail

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server

I am setting up a mail server using postfix and dovecot. I am using virtual users that are stored in a sql database. I've checked the mail queue is empty and the logs show that the mail is received but not forwarded. I've posted the relevant parts of the main.cf and master.cf below:

main.cf

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf,mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-email2email.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

master.cf

```
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/local/libexec/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
```

I've also tried replacing /usr/local/libexec/dovecot/deliver with a shell script which would log if the command executed, but no log is saved.

Comment: What do the logs mention? Does it mention postfix handing over the mail to dovecot? And does dovecot log anything at all after that? Could you show an excerpt from the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look there, you might be found some step you forgot.

[How to install Postfix and Dovecot](http://server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_5&p=mail)

Look on the step on the right menu to find what you missed

I'm assuming you have a CentOS, but if it's not your distro then look on the other os menu.

Comment: I looked at the directions for Ubuntu and I have pretty much everything that is relevant for my configuration. The link you posted doesn't use Dovecot LDA so it isn't really covering what I need. I really would just like to figure out a more verbose way of seeing whats going on so I can find out why dovecot isn't executing.

Comment: That's a shame that this link didn't help you. Have you try looking the log?